# storing and retrieving stored file in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

A trivial scenario:

1) Symlink public/storage to storage/app/public using

```
php artisan storage:link
```

2) Upload file using

```
$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
```

3) In my understanding, I should be able to access the file under this url - `www.example.com/storage/avatars/avatar.jpg

However, the path I get in the third step is actually public/avatars/avatar.jpg, so I end up replacing the 'public/' part with '' to have a correct path.

It seems that I am missing something, but I just can't find exactly what.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When using the public disk, you should store the file in the public disk.

You can specify the disk in the 2nd parameter of the store function.

```
$path = $request->file('avatar')->store(
    'avatars', 'public'
);
```

This makes sure that the file is stored in `storage/app/public`, the `storage` symlink in the public directory points to `storage/app/public`.

Now you can simply use:

```
asset('storage/avatars/avatar.jpg');
```

And it will retrieve the file from `storage/app/public/avatars/avatar.jpg`

---

You might want to check `storeAs` to rename the filename or use a subdirectory to make sure your filenames are unique.

Comment: Dude, thats perfect :)