# How can I store avatar(image file) through Auth/RegisterController while user registration?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

My intention is to store a profile pic with user registration. I am using Laravel 6 User Authentication.  I tried to do it in given method.

My html code is like this..

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
        @error('name')
            <div>{{$message}}</div>
        @enderror
    <input type="file" name="avatar" placeholder="Profile photo"><br>
        @error('avatar')
            <div>{{$message}}</div><br>
    @enderror
</form>
```

I added validation in Auth/RegisterController.validator(). 
I added fields to store data to create function.
RegisterController class is given below..

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'avatar' => ['mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif','required','max:10000']
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'avatar' => file($data['avatar'])->store('avatars')
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I try to run this code, this error will occur

```
Error
Call to a member function store() on array
http://localhost:8000/register
```

Note: I removed email, password and other fields just to reduce number of lines..

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045474/storing-and-retrieving-stored-file-in-laravel-5-4

Comment: The problem is, RegisterController doesn't have Request $req. It only has (array $data) which has the file.  @OmarAbbas

Comment: can't you make it request object instead of array ?
`use Illuminate\Http\Request;` and `Request $request` like that ?

Comment: It is auth/RegistrationController, automatically created by laravel. I am just customizing it. I don't if I can change it. @OmarAbbas

Comment: so you might want to try it.

Comment: This error will occur when I try to make Request.  Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\-----------\vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\RegistersUsers.php on line 34  @OmarAbbas

Comment: `create(Request $data)` did you do that ? also `'avatar' => ['image','mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif','required','max:10000']`

Comment: Yes, I did, error "must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given" is comming @OmarAbbas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload avatar with laravel default registration by doing following steps.

1) Add avatar field in your migration

```
$table->string('avatar');
```

2) Add `avatar` field in `$filable` in User model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'avatar',
];
```

3) Add avatar input field in `register.blade.php`

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="avatar" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Avatar') }}</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="avatar" type="file" class="form-control @error('avatar') is-invalid @enderror" name="avatar" value="{{ old('avatar') }}" required autocomplete="avatar" autofocus>

        @error('avatar')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

4) Add avatar in the `validator` function for validation

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
        'avatar' => ['required', 'image'],
    ]);
}
```

5) Handle file upload in `create` function

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $request = app('request');
    if ($request->hasfile('avatar')) {
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

        //Implement check here to create directory if not exist already 

        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save(public_path('uploads/avatars/' . $filename));
    }

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'avatar' => !empty($filename) ? $filename : 'default_avatar.png',
    ]);
}
```

6) Before you try to Run this make sure you have Image Class available in your controller, If you don't have image class you can include it in your project by doing following steps.

```
composer require intervention/image
```

Now open the config/app.php file. Add this to the $providers array.

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

Next add this to the $aliases array.

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

Now include Image class in User Controller like this

```
use Image;
```

Try to run your project, it should work fine.