# Laravel Storage path not matching

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I can store files to public folder, when receiving the file I also store the url in the database.

I can access the file using domain/storage/profile/img.jpeg but the url stored in db is showing me /public/profile/img.jpeg

```
$path = $request->file('image')->store('public/profile');
$user->image()->create(['url' => $path]);
```

The public prefix in url is wrong, this needs to be storage, so I can show the image in the frontend.
What is the correct here?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [storing and retrieving stored file in Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045474/storing-and-retrieving-stored-file-in-laravel-5-4)

Comment: Almost :) 
$path = $request->file('image')->store('profile','public');
$user->image()->create(['url' => Storage::url($path)]);
Used Storage::url($path), so now the url is prefixed with storage :)